# Changing URL in finished apk by the clients

Tags: android

I made an .apk which shows some web page (advert). Now URL of that web page is simply hard-coded.

I have several clients, who receive mine .apk. They want to set their own URL in their .apk. I don't know URLs beforehand. Client can change his URL on his own, without my knowledge nor help.

How to do it? It's important to make it user-friendly. The easier way for the client, the better. The clients have no idea about programming. They can't build and sign the .apk. Also, the easier to implement, the better.

Example:

I give .apk to a client. He sets his URL to `www.clientA.com`. He puts his .apk on Google Play. After some time, he changes his URL to `www.anotherSiteOfClientA.com`. If it is needed, he updates his .apk on Google Play.

My ideas:

1. XML file for the URL. The problem is that it's not easy for the client to change this XML file when it's already packed into .apk.
2. Another idea is a web service. But it's too much work on my side - internet connection in app, maintaining server, registering clients etc.

Comment: Your client is the end user. or he redistribute the app.

Comment: @hasan He redistributes the app. Well, what will be the difference?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no easy way as you wish exists :)

Comment: the difference that. you can write a text file to the user external storage at first time app opened with the existing urls and he can change those by opening the text file

Answer (score 0):

Just use Provide a Database in your App and let the User manipualte it qith SQLite Database explorer. He has to unpack the .apk file and manipulate it. Please keep in mind that the customer has to build and sign the apk on its own. There is a tool for that purpose: [LINK TO XDA DEVELOPERS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=882742)

Have a look at this [Link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Or you can just put your URLs in the strings.xml and the customer is able to manipulate this file.

Edit: Update cause of comments
If this is not the solution the most comfortable way for the customer is to build a Webfrontend and a database for each customer and load the URLs from this webservice at startup, when there is an update.

Comment: If the client requires to build an apk, he can also use an XML. I think Adam is not looking for this solution

Comment: Exactly, client can't build and sign the .apk.